# Does The size of the Key of a Map have any impact?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Does The size of the Key of a Map have any kind of impact (eg in Performance) in any kind of Map implementation (eg HashMap)?

Would the following iteration be influenced by the Size of the Key object?

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
//...
for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the size of the key object does not matter for the performance of iterating a map.

Note that variables of non-primitive types are always references in Java (they're not the objects themselves, as in C++). It doesn't matter if the reference points to a small or a large object.

Comment: Even If the Key is a Datatype, eg int ?

Comment: Collection does not support primitive types

Answer (score 0):

You can only use references as keys anyway, so it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean by the 'size' of an object, given that an object can only contain primitives, and references to objects.

I would suspect that for a HashMap, the `hashCode()` function will influence performance to some degree. Whether this depends on the size of the key depends on the *implementation* of `hashCode()`. A similar proviso applies to the `equals()` method.

Comment: For iterating a `HashMap`, the `hashCode()` method is not called, so that wouldn't matter. The complexity of the `hashCode()` method could ofcourse have some impact when storing or looking up values in the map.

Comment: Granted for iteration. I think the question is a little more general than that, however

Comment: I meant the size of an Object in Memory.